# how to do a hard close of a websocket client in Java Script

Tags: javascript, websocket

hello to all the people and thanks for reading, i have a network that force me to close the websocket connection in JS if i want that the serveur receive something. So is there a way of doing a hard close on the client side like with normal socket in python?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/close

Comment: yes, but with close the time is still pending

Comment: That's the only option you have to forcibly close a websocket in javascript. Based on your question history, I'd say you should work on figuring out why your network is behaving abnormally and fix that. Once that's done, you'll be able to do things in a normal fashion rather than spending time trying to figure out non-standard work-arounds.

Comment: you have already done a websocket serveur